# How do I import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I need to use this widget:

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
```

But when I start the app, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` so what dependency should I add to `build.gradle` in order for me to be able to use this?

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'`

Comment: I get this warning: `This support library should not use a different version (22) than the compileSdkVersion (21)` Is there a 21 version of the appcompat-v7?

Comment: @J.K. change your `compileSdkVersion` to 22 in the build.gradle

Comment: Is it safe to do so?

Comment: If you're stick with `21` then use `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'`

Comment: @J.K. since you are using appcompat then there is nothing wrong having it as 22 or 21 if you are using older version of the appcompat, if you are just starting the project then go for `23.1.1` instead

Comment: By now you should have updated to this compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your `compileSdkVersion` for this requirement.

```
compileSdkVersion 22 // compileSdkVersion is the version of the compiler used in building the app
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

Then call

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```

Then **Clan-Rebuild-Sync** .